# Getting Cognito data (i.e. requestContext) in AWS Lambda using nest.js

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, nestjs

I'm following the example in https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-typescript-nest

**What I've done**

1) Successfully deployed this to AWS and added a Cognito authorizer (I've verified all this works and I'm getting user data in requestContext).

2) Setup NestJS to handle routing.

**What I need to do**

Hand the `event` and `context` variables to either the NestJS controller or an injectable service so I can do further verification and personalization.

**main.ts snippit where request are first routed.  Notice event and context**

```
async function bootstrapServer(): Promise<Server> {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    try {
      const expressApp = require('express')();
      const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, expressApp);
      nestApp.use(eventContext());
      await nestApp.init();
      cachedServer = createServer(expressApp, undefined, binaryMimeTypes);
    }
    catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
  return Promise.resolve(cachedServer);
}

export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  cachedServer = await bootstrapServer();
  // LOOK HERE!!!!!!
  // How do I pass  event and context
  return proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
}
```

And here is the controller

**controller snippit where I'd like to use event and context**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  // how do I access event and context in this controller class?
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('hello')
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally tracked this down.

[aws-serverless-example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/tree/master/examples/basic-starter) gave me the hint I needed.

Part of [aws-serverless-express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) is a middleware that will add the event information to the `req` body.

**In app.ts (or whatever your launch file is)**

```
import * as awsServerlessExpressMiddleware from "aws-serverless-express/middleware";
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.apiGateway.event);
});
```

**and in the controller/resolver**

```
  @Query(returns => String)
  async eventCreate(@Context() context, @Info() info): Promise<string> {
      let c = context;
      return Promise.resolve("WTF");
  }
```